# Covariance in different FW causes Code Break?

Tags: c#, inheritance, .net-4.0, covariance

I saw Jon Skeet's lecture at the  NDC 2010

He mentioned something interesting :

```
public Class Base
{
 public void Foo(IEnumerable<string> strings){}
}

public Class Child:Base
{
 publc void Foo(IEnumerable<object> objects) {}
}

Main :

List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("aaa");
Child c = new Child();
c.Foo(lst);
```

With C# 3 it will call : `Base.Foo`

With C# 4 it will call : `Child.Foo`

I know it's because covariance

**Question :**

Isn't it a bit code breaking change ?
Is there any workaround so this code will continue work as it was on ver 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's a breaking change. Any time you make a prevously-invalid conversion legal, it's a breaking change.

Unfortunately, it's very hard to add features to the language without making *any* breaking changes. There are a few more around events in C# 4 if you *really* want to look for them. It's unlikely that these will affect most developers, of course.

There were similar breaking changes between C# 1 and C# 2, where the implementation used would have changed between different versions for this code:

```
using System;

public delegate void StringAction(string x);

public class Base
{
    public void Foo(string x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

public class Child : Base
{
    public void Foo(object x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child");
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Child c = new Child();
        StringAction action = new StringAction(c.Foo);
        action("x");
    }
}
```

In this case the compiler actually gives a warning:

```
Test.cs(26,31): warning CS1707: Delegate 'StringAction' bound to
        'Child.Foo(object)' instead of 'Base.Foo(string)' because of new
        language rules
```

Comment: Thank you @jon is there any site that centerlize the code breaking changes from ver 1 to ver 2 ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Here's one for C# 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855831(v=vs.110).aspx - I don't know if there are similar ones for earlier versions.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It's not really appropriate to add comments like this. You don't need my help - you need *someone's* help. Write the best question you can, and I'm sure someone will answer. I note that you decided to add a comment a mere 7 minutes after asking. Patience, please. Imagine if everyone who thought I might be able to help with their question started adding comments on other posts.

Answer (score 5):

Jon is of course right; it is a breaking change. An even easier way to see that breaking change is:

```
object x = new List<string>();
if (x is IEnumerable<object>) 
    Console.WriteLine(4);
else
    Console.WriteLine(3);
```

In C# 3 that prints 3; in C# 4 it prints 4.

When you change the type system, you change the results of overload resolution; that's just how it goes.  The benefit of the feature outweighs the pain of the possible breaks.

Is there a workaround? Yes. Don't call Child.Foo in the first place:

```
Base c = new Child();
c.Foo(list);
```