# Covariance beats concrete type?

Tags: c#, inheritance, .net-4.0, covariance

to be honest- ive asked (a part of this question) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335278/covariance-in-different-fw-causes-code-break)
but now i have a different - related question.

```
public class Base
{
    public void Foo(IEnumerable<string> strings)  { }
}

public class Child : Base
{
    public void Foo(IEnumerable<object> objects) { }
}


List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("aaa");
Child c = new Child();
c.Foo(lst);
```

(n C# 3 it will call : `Base.Foo`
in C# 4 it will call : `Child.Foo`)

*Im in FW4 ! , lets talk about it*

with all the respect to covariance : 
when I write  `c.Foo(lst);` (  `lst` is `IEnumerable` of STRING !)  -

it sees **both** signatures !!!  but STILL - it chooses `IEnumerable<object>` ??

does covariance stronger than the concrete  type itself ?

Comment: You can force it to choose one of the methods by assigning a signature. `c.Foo((IEnumerable<string>)lst)` in your situation, neither signature is a match for the actual concrete type so you should make no assumptions. (The answer below gives the rationale from the spec for the choice, which apparently is different from 3.0, but in these grey areas I prefer just to explicitly define the behavior with a cast)

Comment: @jamietre, no, that doesn't work. Your code will still invoke the method from `Child`.

Comment: Well you've just destroyed my whole world! Sure enough. It appears that the "set of candidate methods" is reduced before disambiguation with casts.

Comment: This is disturbing. Moving from C# 3.0 to C# 4.0 without doing any changes to the code could break the existing code.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yep... it is disturbing....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not because covariance is stronger, but because C# chooses the “closer” method first. So, it looks at `Child.Foo()`, decides it is applicable (thanks to covariance) and doesn't even look at `Base.Foo()`.

The assumption here is that specific type “knows” more, so its methods should be considered first.

See §7.6.5.1 of the C# 4 spec:

> The set of candidate methods is reduced to contain only methods from the most derived types: For each method C.F in the set, where C is the type in which the method F is declared, all methods declared in a base type of C are removed from the set.

Comment: and if i want the base func ?

Comment: Then you need to use a cast: either implicit by changing the variable type to `Base`, or explicit: `((Base)c).Foo(lst)`.

Comment: Or you can use the `base` keyword if you are making the call within `Child`: `base.Foo(lst);`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes `Error 45 Keyword 'base' is not available in a static method`

Comment: @svick `methods is reduced ` --- meaning in compile time...right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, yes this happens when compiling the method, it does not depend on any runtime information.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Inheritance applies to instance methods, not static methods.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes the exeuting command is at main which is static. i cant use base there.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You can use the `base` keyword only from inside of a derived class in order to access a method of the base class. In this case from within the class `Child` itself.